# ApplicationMailerのアクションに、配列を引数に渡すとSerializationErrorになる

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

質問させていただきます。

RubyonRailsで、サイトを作成しております。
モデルが更新された際に
複数の宛先へのメールの送信を行おうと考えています。
しかしMailerに送信したいユーザー一覧を渡すとエラーとなってしましました。

ユーザー一覧は、Applicantsという別のモデルのuser_idと
一致するユーザーを抽出しております。

何か解決策があればご教授いただければと思います。

---

## エラーメッセージ

```
ActiveJob::SerializationError in EventsController#update
Unsupported argument type: ActiveRecord::Relation
```

---

---

## events_controller.rb

```
def update
  if  @event.update(event_params)
    applicants = @event.applicants
    @users = User.where(id: applicants.pluck(:user_id))
    EventMailer.update_to_applicants_email(@users,@event).deliver_later
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

---

---

## event_mailer.rb

```
class EventMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'xxx@example.com'

  def update_to_applicants_email(users,event)
      @event = event
      mail to: users.pluck(:email)
      mail(subject: "#{@event.name}が更新されました")
  end
end
```

---

---

## pryで@usersを確認

```
pry(#<EventsController>)> @users
=>[#<User:0x007fef31ec4668
  id: 14,
  email: “111@example.com",
  中略
  >,
  #<User:0x007fef31ec4528
  id: 15,
  email: “222@example.com",
  中略
  >]
```

---

なお、試しに@usersを@userにし、1人のuserを引き渡したところ、
上記のエラーは発生しませんでした。

---

## pryで@userを確認

```
pry(#<EventsController>)> @user
=>#<User:0x007fef35520518
  id: 14,
  email: "111@example.com",
  中略
>
```

---

よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

エラーメッセージにもありますが、`Unsupported argument type: ActiveRecord::Relation` です。

ids の配列を渡しましょう。

```
def update
  if  @event.update(event_params)
    applicants = @event.applicants       
    @users = User.where(id: applicants.pluck(:user_id))

    # 渡すのは、シリアライズできる要素で
    user_ids = @users.map(&:id)
    EventMailer.update_to_applicants_email(user_ids ,@event).deliver_later


  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end

class EventMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'xxx@example.com'

  def update_to_applicants_email(user_ids ,event)

      # 取り出すときに復旧する
      users = User.where(id: user_ids)
      @event = event
      mail to: users.pluck(:email)
      mail(subject: "#{@event.name}が更新されました")
  end
end
```

ApplicationMailer (というか内部で使っている Activejob) は、キューに積むときに、文字列に変換します。変換できない形式だとエラーです。変換できるのは下記と、array, hash です。

[TYPE_WHITELIST = [ NilClass, Fixnum, Float, String, TrueClass, FalseClass, Bignum, BigDecimal ]](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activejob/lib/active_job/arguments.rb#L37)

では、なぜ一つの時だけ成功するかというと、globalid というのが絡んできますが、長くなるので、知りたければ検索してみてください。

Comment: 上記で無事解決できました。解決方法と、その背景についてアドバイス頂きありがとうございます。